# Installing fingerprint reader in fedora 17

Tags: fedora-17, fingerprint

I have a dual-boot system of fedora 17 and windows 7. My laptop is hp pavilion dv-6 6119 tx. The fingerprint reader on my laptop works well with windows 7 but does not work with fedora 17. How can i enable it?
What i have already done.
I have tried installing fprintd using

> yum install fprintd

and then used the command

> fprintd-enroll

but i got an error saying no devices found.
Also, lsusb produced this.

> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
>   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
>   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0018 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
>   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:02ac Acer, Inc 
>   Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
>   Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1bcf:000a Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
>   Bus 002 Device 005: ID 12d1:14c9 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
>   Bus 002 Device 006: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
>   Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0a5c:21b4 Broadcom Corp. BCM2070 Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR

Comment: Did you already go through https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Configuring_a_fingerprint_reader

Comment: Won't work.. I have tried. Fingerprint reader option isn't highlighted at all

Comment: Ok.  Just trying to determine what you have done already, what you haven't done, what the machine is telling you, etc.  All that information needs to be in the details of your question, to avoid people telling you to do things you've already done... or conversely, people not suggesting things you *need* to do, because they just don't want to assume anything.  Follow?

Comment: Validity Sensors, Inc. makes fingerprint readers, so it looks like at some level, the reader is acknowledged by the OS

Comment: Yes it is identifying the fingerprint reader but the fprintd isn't recognizing it.

Comment: it is *possible* that your device is newer than is supported by libfprint http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint/ and I'm trying to determine if that is the case now...

Comment: Interesting Archlinux forum thread from last year https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1167220 stating issues with a lack of drivers for a Validity Sensors fingerprint scanner, HP DV6, and no fprint support.  However, there is a link to an RPM provided by Validity Sensors http://www.validityinc.com/uploads/hp-2011/bnb/sle11sp1/i586/Validity-Sensor-Setup-1-1.i586.rpm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/maffmeier/fprint_vfs5011

this will add support for your Validiry fingerprint device (138a:0018)

You need to download and compile

Good luck